# How should I prophesy the sort method?

Tags: php, doctrine-mongodb, prophecy

I am using the [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) and I am not sure how to prophesy the sort method.

[Source](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#sorting-results)

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Article')
->sort('createdAt', 'desc');
```

My code is:

UserRepository - Method All

```
public function all(array $input = null)
    {
    $user = UserEntity::class;

    $all = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($user);

    $search = $all->sort(['name' => 'asc'])
            ->getQuery();

        return $search;
    }
```

UserRepositoryTest - prophecy

```
public function testSortingResults()
{
    $output = [
        'name' => 'John',
        'email' => 'john@email.com',
        'phone' => '89564789547',
    ];

    $document = $this->prophesize(DocumentManager::class);

    $queryBuilder = $this->prophesize(QueryBuilder::class);

    $queryBuilder->sort()->willReturn($output)->shouldBeCalled();

    $queryBuilder->getQuery()->willReturn($output)->shouldBeCalled();

    $document->createQueryBuilder(UsuarioEntidade::class)->willReturn($queryBuilder)->shouldBeCalled();

    $repository = new UserRepository($document->reveal());

    $all = $repository->all();

    $this->assertNotNull($all);
    $this->assertEquals($output, $all);
}
```

The error is always this

> Prophecy\Exception\Doubler\MethodNotFoundException: Method `Double\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder\P2::sort()` is not defined.

**I do not understand how to test SORT, because it is not found in QueryBuilder.**

Comment: I think you need  to pass Argument::any(), $queryBuilder->sort(Argument::any())->willReturn($output)->shouldBeCalled();

Comment: Add the parameter in Sort, but the error remains.

Comment: Did you try $queryBuilder->sort(Argument::any(), Argument::any())->willReturn($output)->shouldBeCalled();

Comment: It does not work, you do not find the method.